# OSX docker build error Command not found: -t

Tags: macos, docker

This command used to work just fine a couple of days ago:

```
  docker build  -t dtwill/elasticsearch . | tee build.log
```

Now it errors with the command not found -t. The only thing that has changed in my environment is I installed docker-py via pip.

Here is the output after boot2docker starts:

```
  bash-3.2$ docker version
  Client version: 1.3.2
  Client API version: 1.15
  Go version (client): go1.3.3
  Git commit (client): 39fa2fa
  OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
  Server version: 1.4.0
  Server API version: 1.16
  Go version (server): go1.3.3
  Git commit (server): 4595d4f
```

I'm assuming docker-py has mucked something up...I was trying to execute a fig up when the build failed during an apt-get update so I tried building the image via docker instead of fig....BUT...fig has been installed for a while and the docker build -t was working while fig was installed.

[UPDATE] So, I uninstalled docker-py and updated boot2docker so now the client is at version 1.4.1 but the build command is still erroring.

Comment: Did you tried -t="dtwill/elasticsearch" and worked it?

Comment: Yes I did. Same result. @joh.scheuer Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you enter `docker build --help` what is the output? Maybe try to reinstall docker?

Comment: I re-installed docker, for the 2nd time, it's working again. very strange @joh.scheuer, Thanks! It would be nice to know what caused the hiccup. I can only assume it was the docker-py ???

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer but docker is working again. I uninstalled docker-py (the last thing I installed, when docker was functioning as expected) and re-installed docker with the OS X installer. My Dockerfiles are building again.